# Pyspark format custom timestamp from json file

Tags: datetime, pyspark

I try to read custom timestamps from a loaded json file:

```
{"positionmessage":{"callsign": "PPH1", "name": "testschip-10", "mmsi": 100,"timestamplast": "2019-08-01T00:00:08Z"}}
{"positionmessage":{"callsign": "PPH2", "name": "testschip-11", "mmsi": 200,"timestamplast": "2019-08-01T00:00:01Z"}}
```

The code looks as follows:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import ArrayType, StructField, StructType, StringType, IntegerType, DateType, FloatType, TimestampType

appName = "PySpark Example - JSON file to Spark Data Frame"
master = "local"
# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([
    StructField("positionmessage",
    StructType([
    StructField('callsign', StringType(), True),
    StructField('name', StringType(), True),
    StructField('timestamplast', TimestampType(), True),    
    StructField('mmsi', IntegerType(), True)
    ]))])

file_name = "data.json"
df = spark.read.json(file_name).select("positionmessage.*")
```

How do I get the timestamp displayed as yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS?

Comment: Write a python function using `strptime` then map it to update the dataframe column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the json file with **`schema`** defined.

```
spark.read.schema(schema).json(file_name).select("positionmessage.*")

#+--------+------------+-------------------+----+
#|callsign|        name|      timestamplast|mmsi|
#+--------+------------+-------------------+----+
#|    PPH1|testschip-10|2019-07-31 19:00:08| 100|
#|    PPH2|testschip-11|2019-07-31 19:00:01| 200|
#+--------+------------+-------------------+----+
```

As we have defined **`timestamplast`** as **`TimestampType()`** spark converts the **timestamp** to local time.

---

If you don't want auto converstion to happen then define **timestamplast** as **StringType** and use `to_timestamp()` function to get format as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
spark.read.schema(schema).json("file_name").\
select("positionmessage.*").\
withColumn("timestamplast",to_timestamp(col("timestamplast"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")).\
show()

#using from_unixtime and unix_timestamp functions
spark.read.schema(schema).json("file_name").\
select("positionmessage.*").\
withColumn("timestamplast",from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("timestamplast"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"),'yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss')).\
show()
#+--------+------------+-------------------+----+
#|callsign|        name|      timestamplast|mmsi|
#+--------+------------+-------------------+----+
#|    PPH1|testschip-10|2019-08-01 00:00:08| 100|
#|    PPH2|testschip-11|2019-08-01 00:00:01| 200|
#+--------+------------+-------------------+----+
```

Comment: This gives me: "NameError: name 'to_timestamp' is not defined"

Comment: @jeroen, import functions `from pyspark.sql.functions import *`

Comment: This gives me: `2019-08-01 02:00:08` and `2019-08-01 02:00:01` still ..

Comment: Weird, try with this function, `from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(col("timestamplast"),"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"),'yyyy-MM-dd  HH:mm:ss')` i have updated the answer too..

Comment: Last solution also doesn't work ... I am using pyspark 2.4.5

Comment: As per chat.. use **`StringType`** for **timestamplast** instead of **`Timestamptype`**..!

Comment: Now If I write to csv, it shows the datetime as in the csv as: 
`2019-08-01T00:00:08.000+02:00`
`2019-08-01T00:00:01.000+02:00`

While in the dataframe.show() is shows: 
`2019-08-01 00:00:08`
`2019-08-01 00:00:01`

How can this be?